# filtering for exact match and extracting criteria from a range

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using an advanced filter and ending up with partial matches; however, I need the matching to be exact. The criteria for this filter are always extracted from `B1:B3` on the same worksheet.  Please help me to make the filter exact.

Here is the code for the filter that I'm using:

```
FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

             Sheets("Final").Range("B5:B" & FinalRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
             Range("B1:B3"), Unique:=False
             Range("B1").Select
```

Here is the result:

The criteria include DPB1*01:01:01 only but DPB1*04:01:01:01 is also visible in the filtered data shown underneath the criteria.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Try setting your criteria with a `'=` in front of your values: `'=DPB1*01:01:01`.  The issue is the wonderful `*`.  It is a wildcard and will look for anything so your `*04:` counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found to get around the fact that the `*` is a wildcard in any search is to replace them, filter the data, then put them back.

Put your data on one sheet, I have called mine "Data", starting in "A1":

[image]

Then create a second sheet on which the sorted data will be pasted:

[image]

Then in module add the following code:

```
Sub user5632387()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim dws As Worksheet
Dim sws As Worksheet
Dim finalRow As Long
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim critRng As Range
Dim CpyToRng As Range

Set dws = Worksheets("Data") ' Change to sheet with data
Set sws = Worksheets("Sort") ' Change to sheet on which to sort

With dws
    finalRow = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(finalRow, 1).End(xlToRight))
End With

With sws
    Set critRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight).Offset(2))
    Set CpyToRng = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(5, 1).End(xlToRight))
End With

'change out all "*" for "|"
dataRng.Replace "~*", "|"
critRng.Replace "~*", "|"

'Filter
dataRng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=critRng, CopyToRange:=CpyToRng, _
        Unique:=False



'Replace "*"
critRng.Replace "|", Chr(42)
dataRng.Replace "|", Chr(42)
Range(CpyToRng, CpyToRng.End(xlDown)).Replace "|", Chr(42)


Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You can call this with a button, or assign a short cut key.  It should work.

Obviously if `|` is used in your search area then find some other character that is not a wild card and not used to be a temp place holder.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't seem to help.  I got the same result.

Comment: @user3781528 How are you calling the sub in which this code is placed?  I just tested it again and it worked.

Comment: @user3781528 I have made some edits. I found some errors.  Please try it out.

Comment: why are you copying filtered data to a new sheet? I haven't tried your updated code yet, but previous code worked in Personal workbook but when it was moved to the workbook where my project is DPB1*04:01:01:01 wasn't filtered out.  That is very strange.

Comment: I've tried Enabling Events as well but it didn't help.  I would like to avoid using more than one sheet to do this if possible?

Comment: @user3781528 the problem I found with coping in place is trying to put the `*` back in.  It skips the hidden rows, and I don't know of a way to fix that.  What is the desired reason to use the filter? What are you going to do with the data when you get it?

Comment: I’m going to loop through the visible rows on a sheet and combine values in column C for each distinct value (letter) in column A.  In my example I will have (E1,E2,E3,E4,E5 and E6) associated with “A”. I plan to display combine values for each letter in a corresponding textbox on a Userform.  Each time data is filtered the values will be updated.

Comment: @user3781528 The only way to keep it to one sheet would be to permanently change all `*` to something else.  Though since the desired output is read only using copied data on a second sheet should not hinder the outcome. Sorry I could not help more.